# neo4j javascript example

Tags: javascript, sql, neo4j

What I have not been able to find is simple examples (no third party) of neo4j using javascript.  I have got the desktop of neo4j working and got an example with a third party graph tool working  (the example appears to put the request in the textarea of a DIV and send the request to the graph api and the graph is produced).

I am very familiar with MYSQL, other SQL interaction but having problems interacting with neo4j.  Have done a lot of research but stuck.

From my SQL days there was:
  connect statement (i.e. get a handle and I have got this to work with neo4j)
  send an SQL statement to the database, (in this case it would be cypher)
  get the cursor and process the results  (I assume process the Jason)

I would like the example to:

```
Connect to the database (local and remote)
Show sample cypher commands to fetch data (movie dtabase)
How to store returned results in the javascript program
```

if possible provide a short explanation of Node, HTML, Javascript ie  the javascript goes into app.js and there is index.htnl that refers to app.js.  Do I have to use Node can I access neo4j with Javascript only?

Thanks
Marty

Comment: thanks, very helpful, , much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the official [Neo4j Driver for Javascript](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver). The driver can be used with node.js and there is also a version that runs in a browser.

The repo's README contains links to full documentation and sample projects.

Answer (score 0):

AS `@cybersam` told you, you should use the `neo4j-javascript-driver`.

You can find an example application here : https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-javascript-bolt

And this is snippet on how to perform the connection, a query and to parse the result :

```
// Create a driver instance, for the user neo4j with password neo4j.
// It should be enough to have a single driver per database per application.
var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"));

// Create a session to run Cypher statements in.
// Note: Always make sure to close sessions when you are done using them!
var session = driver.session();

// the Promise way, where the complete result is collected before we act on it:
session
  .run('MERGE (james:Person {name : {nameParam} }) RETURN james.name AS name', {nameParam: 'James'})
  .then(function (result) {
    result.records.forEach(function (record) {
      console.log(record.get('name'));
    });
    session.close();
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

// Close the driver when application exits.
// This closes all used network connections.
driver.close();
```

Moreover, you can also take a look at the *GRAND* stack : http://grandstack.io/
It's stack to build a web application based on React, Neo4j and GraphQl (with Apollo).

Comment: "the version that runs in the browser" what library script do I use that locates the driver? thanks  web_min...??   as there a simple non node example?

Comment: Do you took a look at the README of the Neo4j JS Driver, section ` include in web browser  (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver#include-in-web-browser) ?  For node or in a browser, the code is the same, but the mway to include the lib is different